# Find IP Address and Port of Internet Radio Channel

Tags: ip, port, internet-radio

I am trying to find the IP address and port number of this radio station: http://tunein.com/radio/Classical-South-Florida-897-s30938/
(so I can add it to RhythmBox). I've looked through the source and I can't seem to find it. I have also tried to research a solution to this question but I couldn't find anything useful. Can someone please help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead you can just add the station using the url as illustrated in the article :

http://www.linuceum.com/Desktop/RadioAdd.php

Comment: I believe the actual stream link is encoded in a machine readable form.

Answer (score 1):

Try if you find your radio in here. 
I was trying to find the same and found this website useful. 
http://www.xatworld.com/radio-search/

Comment: Xat doesn't provide IP address as of Jul 2018

Answer (score 0):

A whois search http://whois.domaintools.com/tunein.com shows ip address of 204.69.221.10 . Not sure how to get the port number.

Edit: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers shows commonly used ports, 8000 being for internet radio. I am unable to connect via 204.69.221.10:8000 so @washbow might be right that it may not be the IP hosting the stream.

Comment: The radio seems likely to use port 80 as it did not create a hit on my firewall. However, the IP address listed may only be the server hosting the user readable page rather than the radio stream itself.